# UTF-8 Encoding Issue when uploading CSV

Tags: php, utf-8

I am experiencing some problem on UTF-8 Encoding. I have a CSV file and this is the content of it:

```
Quién tú - Tes,  más , S03
Who you, More, SO2
```

I have extracted it one by one and I have this condition in my loop

```
if(mb_detect_encoding($exploded_value[$i], 'UTF-8', true))
{
   echo $cleaned_data = utf8_encode($exploded_value[$i]);
}
else
{
  echo $cleaned_data=$exploded_value[$i];
}
```

My cleaned data became like this:

```
QuiÃ©n tÃº - Tes
mÃ¡s
S03

Who you
More
SO2
```

Character's like á, ç, ú  gets decoded and when retrieved it gives the wrong output.

Text with Spanish character are being detected as UTF-8 encode character. So, it falls into utf8_encode($exploded_value[$i]). And when utf8_encode perform its process it got decoded.

Declaration of my meta content type is charset=UTF8

Anyone have encountered this issue. Can you share on how did you fix it? Please help. I have googled around and didn't find any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is reversed: you are re-encoding what is already utf-8 encoded, and what is not you pass on as-is.

To fix this just switch the `if` and `else` bodies:

```
if(mb_detect_encoding($exploded_value[$i], 'UTF-8', true))
{
   // already UTF-8
   echo $cleaned_data=$exploded_value[$i];
}
else
{
   // not yet UTF-8
   echo $cleaned_data = utf8_encode($exploded_value[$i]);
}
```